# WordPress url shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have never written any code in php, but im making a wordpress dashboard that requires a redirect to a page based on the username. I want a button on the homepage that takes the loged in user to the right page, so im making a shortcode(don't know if this is the best solution).

So far, from searching online, i have this code:

```
function url_sc() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user() {
        $username = $current_user->login_user {
            $username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=<?php echo $username; ?>"
        }
    }
    return $username_link;
}

add_shortcode( 'username-url', 'url_sc' );
```

I don't know if it will work yet, because i get this syntax error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Can someone explain to me why i get the error, and possibly how to fix it?

Comment: Please add a semicolon after  $username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=<?php echo $username; ?>";

Comment: You seem to be using { where you should be using ; . Also you can't use <?= ?> inside a PHP statement, nor do you need to.

Comment: Please don't update your question with the corrected code - questions should remain as they were for other users who also have similar problems and  the correct answer is already accepted in the "Answers" section.

Comment: @FluffyKitten removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no PHP expert, but I do dabble. That whole function block is laid out wrong, try;

```
function url_sc() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $username = $current_user->user_login;
    $username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=" . $username;
    return $username_link;
}
add_shortcode( 'username-url', 'url_sc' );
```

You can take this a step further here, and create the button html in this code block, then it will output as a complete linked button with the shortcode.

```
function url_sc() {
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   $username = $current_user->user_login;
   $username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=" . $username;
   $button = '<a href="' . $username_link . '" class="button" target="_blank">Go To My Profile Page</a>';
   return $button;
}
add_shortcode( 'username-url', 'url_sc' );
```

Comment: That shows up as "https://testwebpage.no/?username=" on the website

Comment: @KasperAamodt You sure you're logged in currently?

Comment: @Bhautik yes, I'm sure

Comment: when in doubt, lookup wordpress functions https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/

Comment: i think it's meant to be user_login

Comment: No worries, I expanded on it a bit, to help you with the whole 'button' aspect too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. this will check the user logged in or not and also check you're based on your given username.

```
function url_sc() {       
    $current_user  = wp_get_current_user();
    $username      = $current_user->user_login;
    $username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=".$username;       
    return $username_link;
}
add_shortcode( 'username-url', 'url_sc' );
```

Comment: That returns " syntax error, unexpected ';' " on the "$username_link" line

Comment: This answer is confusing. Why are there 2 blocks of code, one of which has many errors? And the other has added in functionality that doesn't exist in the question - a check for a specific username.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you forgot the semicolon after:
`$username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=<?php echo $username; ?>"`  and forgot to escape the php code
this should be:
 `$username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=". echo $username; ."";` 
So the complete code looks like:

```
function url_sc() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user() {
        $username = $current_user->login_user {
            $username_link = "https://testwebpage.no/?username=". echo $username; ."";
        }
    }
    return $username_link;
}

add_shortcode( 'username-url', 'url_sc' );
```

Comment: That returns " syntax error, unexpected ';' " on the "$username_link" line

Comment: This has numerous errors - as well as the ones in the original question, you have added another by echoing the username in the middle of the function that will run when WP is loading.